# Building a list in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

With this code:

```
{% for o in [1,2,3] %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        {% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I get a `TemplateSyntaxError`:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[1,2,3]' from '[1,2,3]'
```

Is there a way of building a list in a template?

Comment: you cannot define a list in django template, but you have to provide the list as an argument from you views.py

Comment: @dominic I meant he cannot initiate a list just like someone does in a normal python code, there are other ways to create lists in template otherwise. But I can't find a reason to use a create a list and use the list items nowhere, also its better to not create lists in templates and define them from views itself. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @dcrodjer Yes, it's obviously not a good idea to create lists and then not use them. Yes, it's better to create them from views.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it via cunning use of the [`make_list`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) filter, but it's probably a bad idea:

```
{% for o in "123"|make_list %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        {% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>p.s. You don't seem to be using `o` anywhere, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.</sup>

Comment: @zhm1126 No, and you probably shouldn't be building `dict`s in templates.

Comment: @zjm1126 If you think you need to build a dict in a template, post a new question with the problem you're trying to solve, and add a comment here with a link to the question and I'll take a look. There's almost certainly a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 83):

We can use split method on str object :

page.html :

```
{% with '1 2 3' as list %}
  {% for i in list.split %}
    {{ i }}<br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Results :

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: providing '1 2 3' directly without the split method will work.

Comment: Yes, but I think you will have spaces considered as list's element.

Comment: You are right, my use case was in a test where I was doing if x in "1 2 3", which was working as expected. In a for loop you could do {% for i in "123" %} and that would work ;)

Comment: Best answer I've seen on this topic

Answer (score 30):

I made this template tag to achieve this goal.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

# use @register.assignment_tag
# only when you're working with django version lower than 1.9
@register.simple_tag
def to_list(*args):
    return args
```

to use it in template:

```
{% load your_template_tag_file %}
{% to_list 1 2 3 4 5 "yes" as my_list %}
{% for i in my_list %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Reference here:
[Django simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

Comment: Simplicity at its best. Works like a charm too, and for every type of data, not only strings (tested on 1.9 with a `simple_tag`). I can't believe something as trivial as this is not already part of the giant engine that Django is!

Comment: The template tag file has to be placed in `templatetags` subdirectory (package) of the website.

Answer (score 12):

The other answers here look like the ticket (at least for what I wanted), so I'll provide an answer as to WHY you might want to do something like this (and perhaps there's a better answer for my case than what's been provided):

I came across this question looking for a way to build 3 very similar, but not identical buttons using Bootstrap. One button might look like

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Modality
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="Modality">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

where the difference between buttons is limited to the text of the button (Modality, on its own line above) and the contents of the  pertaining to the button, which we'll assume is filled dynamically by JS (referencing id="Modality").

If I need to make 10 of these, copy/pasting the HTML seems dumb and tedious, especially if I want to change anything about my button after the fact (like making all of them split-drop-downs) and it goes against DRY.

So, instead, in the template I could do something like

```
{% with 'Modality Otherbutton Thirdbutton' as list %}
  {% for i in list.split %}
    <!-- copy/paste above code with Modality replaced by {{ i }} -->
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Now, granted, in this particular case the buttons add functionality to some related data grid, so the button names could be dynamically filled from django model-sourced data as well, but I'm not at that stage in my design right now, and you can see where this sort of functionality is desirable to maintain DRY.

Comment: I came here for the same reason, simply looking to reduce repetition in a template. +1 for posting a realistic example

Comment: Alternatively, you could just move the repeated code out to a template, have the name of a button as a variable, and do this with ``with`` and ``include``...

Comment: You could, but if I recall correctly, the idea was that the buttons are all in the presentation layer and have nothing to do with logic, so shoving extra variables into logic for the sake of making the template work isn't very clean.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest is to do

```
{% for x in "123" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

drodger is correct, you can't do that in the deliberately-crippled Django template lanuage. Either pass in the list as a context variable when you invoke the template *or* try a template tag like [expr](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/). Then you can say `{% expr [1,2,3] as my_list %}` and then use `my_list` in your for loop.

Comment: @Dominic: I suspect he had a more general case in mind, but I don't know what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe an inspiration. Use the buildin filter `add`.

```
{{ first|add:second }}

first is [1, 2, 3] and second is [4, 5, 6], then the output will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

This filter will first try to coerce both values to integers. 
If this fails, it'll attempt to add the values together anyway. 
This will work on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others. 
If it fails, the result will be an empty string.
```

The official specification,https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference