# Python Value in List

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django and I am wondering how I can accomplish this.  It works fine in python in Linux but the HTML Templating language keeps saying it cannot parse the array.

```
{% if myvalue in ["128","256","512","768","1024","1536","2048","3072","5120","10240"] %}
 <p> Hello World
{% endif %}
```

It says it cannot parse the remainder and then it displays the list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't create arbitrary lists in the Django templating system. You need to pass the created list via your view. See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395230/building-a-list-in-django-templates) for a detailed discussion.