# Django - Template with 'if x in list' not working

Tags: python, django

I have a Django template that looks something like this:

```
{% if thing in ['foo', 'bar'] %}
    Some HTML here
{% else %}
    Some other HTML
{% endif %}
```

The problem is it comes back empty. If I switch to this:

```
{% if thing == 'foo' or thing == 'bar' %}
    Some HTML here
{% else %}
    Some other HTML
{% endif %}
```

it works fine. Is there some reason you can't use `x in list` in Django templates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can. But you can't use a list literal in templates. Either generate the list in the view, or avoid using `if ... in ...`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to achieve that also by creating a custom filter:

*Python* function in `your_tags.py`:

```py
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='is_in_list')
def is_in_list(value, given_list):
    return True if value in given_list else False
```

and passing your list to `html` *django* template:

```html
{% load your_tags %}


{% if thing|is_in_list:your_list %}
    Some HTML here
{% else %}
    Some other HTML
{% endif %}
```

or without passing any list - by creating a string containing your list's values (with a filter you still can't use list literal), e.g.:

```html
{% load your_tags %}


{% if thing|is_in_list:'foo, bar' %}
    Some HTML here
{% else %}
    Some other HTML
{% endif %}
```

[TIP] Remember not to insert *space* after `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279231/4157431) answer. We could use `split` to generate a list inside the template itself. My final code is as follows (I want to exclude both `"user"` and `"id"`)

```
        {% with 'user id' as list %}
        {% for n, f, v in contract|get_fields %}
        {% if n not in list.split %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{f}}</td>
            <td>{{v}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the list from the context data in the view.

Views.py:

```
class MyAwesomeView(View):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list'] = ('foo', 'bar')
        ...
        return context
```

MyTemplate.html:

```
{% if thing in list %}
    Some HTML here
{% else %}
    Some other HTML
{% endif %}
```

Tested on Django version 3.2.3.