# django templates: loop through list of classes/strings

Tags: django, templates

Is there something like:

```
{% for class in "red", "green", "blue" %}
   <div class="{{ class }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

in django templates?

Comment: Better if you send the array or list from view to your template. Then you can do anything you want with this way.

Comment: I don't think that would be a good practice. The view shouldn't be containing any "display-logic" on it. This kind of things should be only in the template or if not posible in a template-tag.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395230/building-a-list-in-django-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, not directly but you can use cycle combined with a list on the fly:

```
{% for cnt in "123"|make_list %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'red' 'green' 'blue' %}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

... another option would be to give your css_classes more generic names like: color_1, color_2, color_3 and then:

```
{% for cnt in "123"|make_list %}
    <div class="color_{{ cnt }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

This would de-couple your css-classes from fixed colors, which is maybe a good idea, if you change the colors later on your css.

---- Update ---

Ok, reading the answers on the link posted by nickromano, I now realize I was wrong. There IS a way of using expr for declaring a real list object on the template. And the split method is better than make_list + cycle :-)

Comment: Nice. That `|make_list` is not really needed I guess. I picked the first suggested solution and instead of "123", I took the first letters of the classes. I am satisfied now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped you. But you should also take a look to the other link. The answers with the split-method could be usefull on the future. I'll definetely keep that in mind for the next time :-)