# Django modelformset_factory UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, django, variables, local, formset

I am getting error message the UnboundLocalError local variable 'Assumptions' referenced before assignment (after line else:). I wonder how is that even possible given that Assumptions is a model and is imported to the views.py. Any advise how to solve it would be highly appreciated. Also, I am trying to create multiple forms based on Assumptions modelform and save them into the database model Assumptions. Please advise if this code is the correct design pattern. Thank you.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import  modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions


def get_assumptions(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'name' in request.POST:      

            formset = modelformset_factory(Assumptions, form = AssumptionsForm, extra = 5)

            if formset.is_valid():

                print('valid form')            

                for form in formset:

                    print('Looping forms')

                    Assumptions =  form.save(commit='False')
                    Assumptions.Name = 'name'
                    Assumptions.save()

    else:

        formset = modelformset_factory(Assumptions, form = AssumptionsForm, extra = 5)

    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**assumptions.html**

```
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
{% for name in ['A', 'B'] %}
<h1>var</h1>
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<input type="submit", name='name', value="save" />
{% endfor %}



</form>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = ['Worst', 'Base', 'Best']
        exclude = ['Name']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Base = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are shadowing the imported `Assumptions` name by assigning a new value to it here:

```
Assumptions =  form.save(commit='False')
```

You should use a different name for your model instance. The usual practice is to use a lowercase name, i.e.

```
assumptions = form.save(commit='False')
assumptions.Name = 'name'
assumptions.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue regarding unbounded error. However, now i get blank page. Is this correct way to do for loop in template {% for name in ['A', 'B'] %} and then pass it to views.py and assign to assumptions.name?

Comment: No, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395230/building-a-list-in-django-templates for building a list within your template. Also fix your input tag so that `name` uses the loop variable, i.e. `<input name="{{ name }}" ...` and get rid of the commas inside the `input` tag

Comment: Thank you for advise! I did as you suggested, however I am still getting empty website. I pushed new updated project files to the git https://github.com/martin1007/test I would highly appreciate any additional help.

Comment: First of all Django won't understand `list.split`, you should probably simply have used `{% for name in "AB" %}` and second, I suggest you to post this as a new question as it has nothing to do with the question title anymore.

Comment: Thanks for insight. Did as advised, however template still does not output any form and save to database. Pushed updated template to git. Reopened new case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203547/django-template-does-not-output-multiple-forms-and-save-to-modelform Any additional suggestions highly appreciated