# Django template does not output multiple forms and save to modelform

Tags: django, forms, templates, modelform

the issue is that template does not output multiple forms and save to Assumptions modelform. I am trying to save input from multiple forms by adding different names from template to Assumptions.Name field in Assumptions model. However, this approach does not work for some reason. Advise how to solve it would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import  modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions


def get_assumptions(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':


        if 'name' in request.POST:      

            formset = modelformset_factory(Assumptions, form = AssumptionsForm, extra = 5)

            if formset.is_valid():

                print('valid form')            

                for form in formset:

                    print('Looping forms')

                    assumptions =  form.save(commit='False')
                    assumptions.Name = 'name'
                    assumptions.save()



    formset = modelformset_factory(Assumptions, form = AssumptionsForm, extra = 5)    



    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**assumptions.html**

```
{% for name in "AB" %}
    <div class="form">
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}

    <table id="formset" class="form">
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
      <thead><tr>
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr></thead>
      {% endif %}
      <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <td>
        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
        {% if forloop.first %}
          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
          {{ hidden }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
          {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
          {{ field }}
        </td>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="{{name}}" value="save" />
    </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Base = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = ['Worst', 'Base', 'Best']
        exclude = ['Name']
```