# How to assign HTML class in django template depending object's field value

Tags: django, django-templates

**models.py:**

```
class MyText(models.Model)
    value = models.TextField()
    appearance = models.Charfield(
        max_length=50, 
        choices=(
            ('bold', 'Bold'),
            ('italic', 'Italic'),
        )
    )
```

**object:**

```
a_lot_of_text = MyText(value='a lot of text', appearance='bold')
```

I pass this object via `context` in `views.py` into HTML template. And I want to check (in HTML) what kind of appearance `a_lot_of_text` has, and use certan `class` for its `<div>` element. In other words, I want to get smth like this:

**mytemplate.html (pseudocode):**

```
<style>
    bold_class {...}
    italic_class {...}
</style>

{% if object.appearance == 'bold' %}
    {% somehow i will use 'bold_class' %}
{% elif object.appearance == 'italic' %}
    {% somehow i will use 'italic_class' %}
{% endif %}

{% for word in object.value %}
    <div class="{{class_that_i_have_chosen_in_if-block}}">{{word}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Because there is a lot of `word` in `a_lot_of_text` I would like to check my class 1 time, before my `for-block` and use it there. I think I could make [my own assignment Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37755722/7626537) - is it correct solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use custom assignment tag or you can do what you want using built-in tag `with` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#with

```
# models.py

class MyText(models.Model)
    value = models.TextField()
    appearance = models.Charfield(
        max_length=50, 
        choices=(
            ('bold', 'Bold'),
            ('italic', 'Italic'),
        )
    )

    def class_name(self):
        if self.appearance == 'bold':
            ...
            return 'bold-class'
        elif  self.appearance == 'italic':
            ...
            return 'italic-class'
        ...


# template.html

{% with block_class=object.class_name %}
    {% for word in object.value %}
        <div class="{{ block_class }}">{{ word }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

But also, if you are looking for simple solution - get names or yours CSS-classes based on `appearance` value.
Then you just need to use `appearance` value and add '-class' to it:

```
{% for word in object.value %}
    <div class="{{ object.appearance }}-class">{{ word }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```