# I can't make Javascript copy my string as I want it

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have javascript that is running on a django app. I get a list from my views.py and after that I want to get the img url

The first line of code gets it and console log shows exactly what I want `pictures/logo.png`

The problem is that in the third line of code the variable `img` shows me this: `%22%2bimg%2b%22`

Can you see what I'm missing?

```
img = data[i].fields.imagen.substring(13);
console.log(img);

html += "<div class='brick "+size+"' style='background-image: url(\"{% static '"+img+"' %}\")'><div class='cover'>"+nombre+"</div></div>"
```

Comment: what does console.log(img) returns in the console?

Comment: pictures/logo.png

Comment: take img as python raw string and then give it to your javascript, might help.

Comment: kinda newb on the python part, im doing the javascript, care to explain a bit? im looking for it tho

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070398/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-code perhaps?

Comment: Django automatically HTML quotes everything for security. You have to mark you string as safe if you want to prevent it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Comment: Solved it, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, i didn't have to write the

```
{% static '"+img+"' %}
```

part like that, messed up some stuff, just had to put it like this

```
 url(\"/static/"+img+"\")
```