# Django templating define a variable

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Hey i have a problem with defining a variable in Django templates. I don´t know hat im doing wrong.

```
{% set name="World" %}     
<html>
<div>Hello {{name}}!</div>
</html>
```

Django Invalid block tag on line 1: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value of a variable inside a template code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070398/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-code)

Comment: You are almost certainly not using Jinja here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to be using a "with" rather than "set".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with

```
{% with name='world'%}
    <html>
    <div>Hello {{name}}!</div>
    </html>
{% endwith %}
```