# Did you forget to register or load this tag in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In the django project I am working on, when I add this line `{% set alpha = SafeExec.objects.get(testcase=a_test) %}` to my html, it is showing this error. How to get rid of it?

This is my template code:

```
{% for a_testcases in testcases %}
    <li><i>{{ a_testcases.0.program.name }}</i> <br/>
    {% for a_test in a_testcases %}
        {% set alpha = SafeExec.objects.get(testcase=a_test) %}
            {{ alpha.cpu_time }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input id="id{{ a_test.id }}" type="checkbox" name="testcases_cbx" value="{{ a_test.id }}" checked/>
    <label style="display: inline" for="id{{ a_test.id }}">{{ a_test.name }}</label> <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

This is screenshot of error:[image: Template syntax error. Did you for get to load this tag?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do *any* of this in the template. `set` isn't a template tag; `SafeExec` won't exist in the context; and you can't call methods with arguments in templates anyway.

Without seeing your models I can't tell exactly what you need to do, but it looks like the testcase has a foreign key to SafeExec, so you should just do:

```
{{ a_test.safeexec.cpu_time }}
```

Comment: It is not working. It is showing error: Could not parse the remainder: ' a_test.safe_exec.cpu_time' from 'for a_test.safe_exec.cpu_time'

Comment: Sorry that `for` shouldn't have been there, edited. But you do need to show your models.

Comment: Working !! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use "with" tag if you want to create any variable in django template.

check this answer

[How to set a value of a variable inside a template code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070398/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-code)

Comment: For this I suggest to do all your database related operation or businness logic in view file only, you will get more ways to perform operations.