# Conditional test not working using pythonanywhere with python and flask

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

My simple conditional test is not working.

Here is the flask_app.py code:

```
testing_conditional_args = []
testing_conditional_args.append("a")
testing_conditional_args.append("b")
testing_conditional_args.append("c")
@app.route("/testing_conditional/", methods=['POST'])
def testing_conditional():
    if request.method == "POST":
          return render_template("testing_conditional.html", testing_conditional_args=testing_conditional_args)
    return redirect(url_for('testing_conditional'))
```

Here is the html template (testing_conditional.html):

```
var0 = {{testing_conditional_args[0]}} <br>
var1 = {{testing_conditional_args[1]}} <br>
var2 = {{testing_conditional_args[2]}} <br>
{% if var1 == "b" %}
    args var1 and "b" are equal<br>
{% endif %}
{% if var1 != "b" %}
    args var1 and "b" are not equal<br>
{% endif %}
{% if "a" != "b" %}
    args "a" and "b" are not equal<br>
{% endif %}
{% if "a" == "a" %}
    args "a" and "a" are equal<br>
{% endif %}
```

The output in the web browser shows that var1 is "b", but the conditional test does not work.

```
var0 = a
var1 = b
var2 = c
args var1 and "b" are not equal
args "a" and "b" are not equal
args "a" and "a" are equal
```

It says that var1 and "b" are not equal when it seems they should be.
Why is var1 not recognized as "b"?

Comment: First of alll, you can not do variable assignments in template like normal python.
Second, you would like to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070398/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-code)

Comment: Yes, I knew it wasn't the correct way to assign variables and your suggested post showed me how to do it correctly:
            {% set var0=testing_conditional_args[0] %}
            {% set var1=testing_conditional_args[1] %}
            {% set var2=testing_conditional_args[2] %}
Now it works the way I wanted!!

Comment: To give you credit for answering the question you need to have an answer in addition to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional test works using the set command:

```
        {% set var0=testing_conditional_args[0] %}
        {% set var1=testing_conditional_args[1] %}
        {% set var2=testing_conditional_args[2] %}

        {% if var1 == "b" %}
            args var1 and "b" are equal<br>
            <div style="color:blue; font-size:200%; text-align:left" >"Conditional Formatting"</div>
        {% endif %}
```