# Django: can we create a variable using set in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Can we create a variable using set in django template?

like this

```
{% set isfound = False %}
```

if so I am getting this error

```
Invalid block tag on line: 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load 
this tag?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070398/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-code

Comment: https://www.pythoncircle.com/post/685/for-loop-in-django-template/