# How do I update a variable set by 'with' in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, with-statement

Following is the code where I need to update a variable.

```py
{% with a=1 %}
{% for x in object_list %}
    {% if 'clone' in x.game and a is 1 %}
        <div class="alert alert-primary">
            <h2 class="p-3">{{ x.title }}</h2>
        </div>
        {{ a=2 }} # here is where I update it
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

but instead of `{{ a=2 }}` setting `a` to 2, it throws the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '=2' from 'a=2'
```

Comment: The idea is *not* to *update* variables. The `{% with a=1 %}` will assign a value to `a`, Django templates do *not* redefine the `a` variable. Such logic does *not* belong in the template, but in the view.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But how to do that in the view? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reassign a variable in a `with` template tag.

You should do that in the backend (view) or by loading the variable into JavaScript and perform what you want to do it it can be client-side.

Comment: Can you give some hints on how to do that in the backend? Many thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at this this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070398/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-code

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone is saying, you can do this logic in the view. But, instead of reassigning `a` to 2, you can just add 1:

```
{% with a=1 %}
{% for x in object_list %}
    {% if 'clone' in x.game and a is 1 %}
        <div class="alert alert-primary">
            <h2 class="p-3">{{ x.title }}</h2>
        </div>
        {{ a|add:"1" }} # this is the changed code
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: oh, sorry, I guess I was writing for Django 3.2 (the latest version at the time of writing). Sorry about that, but I do recommend to start using Django 3 as it has lot's of new features. :)