# Django Template Language Variable Usage

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display a form on my webpage. Part of the template file responsible for displaying the form is shown below:

```
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
{% count = 0 %}

{% if count == 0 %}
    <label class="right" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% count += 1 %}

{% elif count == 1 %}
    <label class="left" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

So you may notice that I am expecting two choices in `poll.choice_set.all`. and my goal is to display both differently (as you can see by the class of the labels). So the way I tried to do this was by declaring a counter which would initially display one choice in a format and increment the counter, and then display the second choice in a different format because `count` was incremented.

I am very sure that this is completely wrong, and cannot be done this way. I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to achieve what I want to do.

So basically I have a poll object with two choices. I want each choice to be displayed differently (different CSS class).

Comment: Django templates don't allow variable assignments.  In other words, `count += 1` will never work.

Comment: Here's a related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719127/django-template-new-variable-declaration) about it.

Comment: @almostflan Thanks, exactly what I needed to know. I ended up using `forloop.counter` and everything works really well. Django has too much functionality and the Docs are *huge* ... it's so hard to know even a fraction of the fundamental knowledge (for a beginner anyway). Just takes practice I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, it looks like you can use forloop.counter or forloop.counter0, since your hypothetical "choice" variable would change once per loop iteration. You could simplify the

```
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />

    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
        <label class="right" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />

    {% elif forloop.counter0 == 1 %}
        <label class="left" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you want shorter code, you could do this:

```
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label class="{% cycle 'right' 'left' %}" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />

{% endfor %}
```

{% cycle "right" "left" %} will switch between "right" and "left" as the class value every time that tag is encountered, so this would have the side-effect of alterating between "right" and "left" if you wind up with more than 2 options.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. I went with your first suggestion. I actually noticed `forloop.counter` being used and quickly figured I could adapt it to my scenario. Your answer reaffirmed that. Thanks.