# How to do list intersection in django's templating engine?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Ok, So I'm trying to show a simple table with users/roles.

I have a list of Role names and a user is defined as something like...

```
[{
    'Username': 'Bob',
    'Roles': ['Admin']
},
{
    'Username': 'Sheila',
    'Roles': ['Admin', 'Manager']
}]
```

And what I want to produce is something like this...

```
Username     Manager    Admin    SomeRoleNobodyHas
Bob          No         Yes      No
Sheila       Yes        Yes      No
```

I am rendering the view with this context

```
Data = {'Roles': ['Admin', 'Manager', 'SomeRoleNobodyHas'],
        'Users': Users}
```

I assumed this would be trivial (having never touched the templating engine before, I usually return Json). Outputting the column headers is easy so skipping on to the tbody...

First I tried...

```
{% for User in Users%}
    <td>{{User.Username}} ({{User.Id}}) </td>
    {% for Role in Roles%}
        <td>{%if Role in User.Roles%}Y{%else%}N{%endif%}</td>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this gave me a syntax error. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719132/156755) implies I'm trying to do too much in the html, I modified my context to add

```
       'UserTable': [
                     {'Id': x['Id'],
                      'Username': x['Username'],
                      'EmailAddress': x['Email'],
                      'IsLocked': x['IsLocked'],
                      'Roles': dict(zip(Roles, [y in x['Roles'] for y in Roles]))
                      } for x in Users]
```

So now I should have a `User['Roles'][RoleName]` which is guaranteed to exist and will be True or False. I then iterated through `UserTable` instead of `Users`

Unfortunately, I can't work out how to look up a value from a dict when the key comes from another iterator...

```
{% for Role in Roles%}
    <td>{{Role}}: {%if User.Roles.Role == True%}Y{%else%}N{%endif%}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

This always evaluates to false (I believe it's doing `User['Roles']['Role']` not `User['Roles'][Current value of {{Role}}]`) (Yes, I've resorted to trying an explicit `== True` it didn't help).

Maybe there's a method to the madness but what I'm trying to accomplish is clearly presentation logic - which to my mind means it should be possible in the template?

How can I actually get this to work?

Note: I *did* manage to get it working by having roles be a List of Boolean and assuming the order of `Roles` and `User.Roles` were constant but this seems fragile and likely to break in future.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you can't lookup `User['Roles'][Role]` that way in django templates. However, the following code should produce the table you mentioned in the question:

Using this context:

```
all_roles = set(role for role in user['Roles'] for user in Users)
cx ={
  'AllRoles': list(all_roles),
  'Users': Users,
}
```

You can make the table in the template like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    {% for role in AllRoles %}
      <th>{{ role }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for user in UserTable %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ user.Username }}</td>
      {% for role in AllRoles %}
        <th>{% if role in user.Roles %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Hmmm that seems identical to my first example? or am I missing something subtle? Actually, in hindisght, my Q was unclear. I have a list of all possible Roles which is the the `Data = {'Roles': Roles,...}` part was referring to. Apologies for the confusion, I'll update the Q. Assuming your answer is correct I must've had a typo giving me that syntax error. I'll try again.

Comment: @Basic another option is `User['TableRoles'] = [[r, r in User['roles']] for r in Roles]` and in the template: `{% for role, has_role in User.TableRoles %}`

Comment: @Basic would you be able to show the syntax error you mentioned in the question?